# Row Addition or Column Addition in Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

It is a general performance/optimization question for **numpy arrays**.
Say, I have a numpy array **days** in column form:

```
[['Day1']
 ['Day2']
 ['Day3']
 ['Day4']
 ['Day5']]
```

I want to add new columns of data to it which is stored in **data**.
Should I use:

```
1. Append column wise:
    new_data = numpy.append(days, data, axis=1)

2. Append row wise:
    days = numpy.transpose(days)
    data = numpy.transpose(data)
    new_data = numpy.append(days, data, axis=0)
    new_data = numpy.transpose(new_data)
```

Comment: If you want to optimize your code, don't use `np.append` at all unless it's absolutely necessary. It will copy and reassign the data every step. There are much better strategies depending on the concrete application.

Comment: Your `days` contains strings.  What about `data`?  strings as well?  `concatenating` will force everything to the common string dtype.  What's the shape of `data`?  `days` as shown in `(5,1)`.

Comment: @PéterLeéh could you refer me to some sites to read about it or maybe give the terms for such methods?

Comment: @hpaulj Although my data contains only strings, I'd love to know how to handle heterogenous data too. Also, should the shape matter as long as it has 5 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making your column array:

```
In [135]: days = np.array('Day1,Day2,Day3'.split(','))
In [136]: days
Out[136]: array(['Day1', 'Day2', 'Day3'], dtype='<U4')
In [137]: days = days[:,None]
In [138]: days
Out[138]: 
array([['Day1'],
       ['Day2'],
       ['Day3']], dtype='<U4')
```

A sample 2d data array:

```
In [139]: data = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
```

If the arrays already have the right shape, use `np.append`:

```
In [140]: np.append(days, data, axis=1)
Out[140]: 
array([['Day1', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
       ['Day2', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
       ['Day3', '8', '9', '10', '11']], dtype='<U21')
```

But if you look at the `np.append` code you'll see that with an `axis` it just calls `concatenate`.  That's the base function for all these `stacks`.  (`np.append` is a poorly named and conceived cover)

```
In [141]: np.concatenate([days, data], axis=1)
Out[141]: 
array([['Day1', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
       ['Day2', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
       ['Day3', '8', '9', '10', '11']], dtype='<U21')
```

There's another cover that joins columns:

```
In [142]: np.column_stack([days, data])
Out[142]: 
array([['Day1', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
       ['Day2', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
       ['Day3', '8', '9', '10', '11']], dtype='<U21')
```

and if needed it will reshape in the inputs to work as columns:

```
In [143]: np.column_stack([days, np.arange(3)])
Out[143]: 
array([['Day1', '0'],
       ['Day2', '1'],
       ['Day3', '2']], dtype='<U21')
```

But note with all of these examples, the result is string dtype.  If you want to keep `data` as numbers, you don't want to use any of these.

Comment: This comment is not related to the answer but I would like to ask how do you write this code with formatted `In [..] and Out[..] ` statements. Do you copy it directly from jupyter notebook ? I would really appreciate it if you could let me hear the procedure. It would come really handy when I'm writing next time on StackOverflow

Comment: I copy-n-paste from a `ipython` session (console version of `jupyter`).  I have several such terminals running at a time, hence the (sometimes) large row numbers.

Comment: @hpaulj So should I use ```concatenate``` instead of ```append```? How is it better than ```append```? I feel that ```append``` is syntactically better.

Comment: @hpaulj Also, the point of the question is to compare row addition with column addition. For example, in an array in C++, row addition is much better than column addition in terms of performance. Is it the same in numpy arrays?

Comment: `np.concatenate` makes a new array regardless of axis.  I don't recall doing timings, but my impression is that axis doesn't make much difference (as long as dimensions are correct).

Comment: I generally don't like `np.append` for multiple reasons.  For your use it's just another layer of function call.  Too many people treat it like a list `append` clone.  They use it iteratively, get the initial 'empty' array wrong, or ignore its `ravel` action.